# Why can't I Import the math.js file?

Tags: javascript, binary-search, math.js

I tried to write binary search in my code but it seems that everytime I tried to run it. It shows an error message *(**Uncaught ReferenceError: math is not defined**)* eventhough I clearly wrote import math.js file. I'm pretty sure that something went wrong somewhere in my code. Can anyone please explain to me that would be really helpful!

By the way, here's the code:

```
import math.js

var num = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20];
bilnum = num.length,
target = 13;
mid = math.floor((left + right)/2);

function search(){
    left = 0;
    right = num.length - 1;
    while(left <= right){
        if(num[mid] == target){
            return mid;
        }
        else if(target > mid){
            right = num[mid] - 1;
        }
        else{
            left = num[mid] + 1;
        }
        if(target === null){
            document.write("Number doesn't exist")
        }
        document.write("The target index is" + num[target])
    }
}
```

Comment: Hit F12 to bring up the developer console and see if there are additional errors. For what it's worth, JavaScript includes Math.floor and you probably don't need the library for that. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor

Comment: Thank you I just realized that the "M" in math.floor isn't in capital letters :P

Comment: `import math.js`, please read an introduction about how `import` works. Please read the [getting started](https://mathjs.org/docs/getting_started.html).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

two issues:

```
bilnum = num.length,
```

to

```
bilnum = num.length;
```

and

```
mid = math.floor((left + right)/2);
```

to:

```
mid = Math.floor((left + right)/2);
```

Answer (score -2):

Try Math.js (with uppercase M)